# Python Subprocess - Doesn't return anything

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I've seen on here a few other issues running subprocesses with Python, but none have solved the issue I'm having at the moment. Relatively new to Python, so just playing around and I'm sure it's a simple solution.. But I just can't make it work!

I want a subprocess to return some data, and it isn't. So I wrote this basic example to try and get it working but it still isn't. Where am I going wrong? I'm getting no errors or anything, it's just not doing anything.

***sp_test.py***

```
import os
import subprocess

def main():
    subp = subprocess.check_call(['python', 'sp.py'])
    print subp


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and...

***sp.py***

```
def do_something():
    return "Hello World!"


do_something()

exit()
```

Comment: Check call returns to the returncode only. Also you will need to print Hello World. Since the only way is to capture the printed output. Use check_output maybe?

Comment: If you want to see the output use `print(do_something())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your implementation.

**1.**

`check_call` only returns the `returncode` of 0 or throws an exception otherwise. (See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

**2.**

Also you are trying to capture the the value of `Hello World!` by simply returning a value. That won't work using subprocess. If you want to do that, you may want to look into something like Pyro4 (https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/intro.html)

---

Here is one solution if you want to use subprocess still.

First you can use check_output (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). This will capture any output from your subprocess.

Then in your `sp.py` program, you will need to print the result `do_something`.

**sp_test.py**

```
import os
import subprocess

def main():
    subp = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'sp.py'])
    print subp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**sp.py**

```
def do_something():
    return "Hello World!"


print do_something()

exit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll try and get it working with it! My current implementation prints out nothing. Shouldn't it at least print out the return code?

Comment: Yeah it should. I tested your script on my system and it worked. It printed 0

Comment: Interesting.. It prints nothing for me!

Comment: Shouldn't doesn't make a difference, but what OS are you using?

Comment: Maybe try this simple example: `subprocess.check_call(['echo', 'Hello World!'])`

Comment: That still prints nothing. I am using Mac OSX running Python 2.7.5.

Comment: That's strange. I'm on OSX also, but I have Python 2.7.6. You may want to test your script in a Linux VM if you have one handy.

Comment: I unfortunately don't. It's weird it doesn't work. However I'll look into the options you've provided as you've at least solved my issue of why it wasn't returning a value. Thanks!